# Next JS dynamic import for named export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I am learning next js. I want to call a function `getItem` of https://www.npmjs.com/package/encrypt-storage

Using below code, but I am getting  `TypeError: EncryptStorage.getItem is not a function`

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const EncryptStorage = dynamic(() => import('encrypt-storage').then((mod) => mod.EncryptStorage(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SKK)), { ssr: false });
console.log(EncryptStorage.getItem('aa'));
```

please help me to sort it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**tl;dr**: You need to use `await import(...)` instead of `dynamic(() => import(...))` as the latter is *only* for components.

**The longer version**:

This was confusing to me as well as the docs don't outright state that you *can't* import modules with `dynamic(...)`, only that it should be used to import components:

> React components can also be imported using dynamic imports, but in this case we use it in conjunction with `next/dynamic` to make sure it works just like any other React Component.

And indeed, looking at [this comment](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13417#discussioncomment-18924) from a maintainer you can't use `dynamic(...)` to import modules, only components.

Given this, here's a possible solution:

Also, note that `.getItem(...)` is a method that needs to be called on an *instance* of `EncryptStorage`.

```js
    // Needs to be ran in an `async` context or environment that supports top-level `await`s
    const EncryptStorage = (await import("encrypt-storage")).default;
    const encryptStorage = EncryptStorage(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SKK);
    console.log(encryptStorage.getItem("aa"));
```

And, here's a [sandbox with a full working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-rain-rc495?file=/pages/index.js).

Comment: Thank you so much.. you have saved my life ! But what is the need of .default ? after import ?

Comment: Using `.default` ensures that you import the default export from the module. It's not technically required here (if you look [at the source](https://github.com/michelonsouza/encrypt-storage/blob/b35282d8fe168f41ca689269f3ab67b0239b120e/src/index.ts#L167), `EncryptStorage` is the default export) however, I consider it to be good practice. [Javascript Info](https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports) has a good primer on dynamic imports if you're still curious as well!

Comment: If only I found your answer sooner, I would have a few more strands of hair in my head