# How do I import framer-motion using dynamic import in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, next.js, framer-motion, dynamic-import

I working with [framer-motion](https://www.framer.com/motion/) in my NextJS project. I'm trying to import `{motion}` using Next's `dynamic` import. But unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work.

```js
import { motion } from "framer-motion"
```

I'm trying to convert the above import as a [dynamic](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) import as given below:

```js
const motion = dynamic(() =>
  import("framer-motion").then((module) => module.motion)
)
```

But it throws an error :

```
"Argument of type '() => Promise<ComponentClass<never, any> | FunctionComponent<never> | { default: ComponentType<never>; } | ((<Props>(Component: string | ComponentType<Props>, customMotionComponentConfig?: CustomMotionComponentConfig | undefined) => CustomDomComponent<...>) & HTMLMotionComponents & SVGMotionComponents)>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DynamicOptions<{}> | Loader<{}>'."
```

Whenever I import other things like icons, custom components it works as expected, for example the dynamic import given below works fine :

```js
const DoubleArrowRightIcon = dynamic(() => import("@radix-ui/DoubleArrowRightIcon"), {
  loading: () => <p>..</p>,
})
```

I have looked at other answers and found this [link](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13139) but still, not able to make it work.

Any help please?

Comment: That's most likely because the `motion` export is not a React component itself. `next/dynamic` is meant to be used with React components only.

Comment: @juliomalves yes l think so, I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68323336/next-js-dynamic-import-for-named-export), Is there a way to lazy load expensive items on the page.?The NextJS router/framer motion is more than 40kbs

Comment: Is framer-motion used across your whole app, or is it specific to certain parts/components? Potentially, you could dynamically import those parts/components only. Otherwise, if it's used everywhere, I don't think you have much choice.

Comment: @juliomalves I won't say whole app, I'm doing micro-interactions with it, sort of hover animations. Even in this case, how can I dynamically import? Say for example ,I'm doing this -> 

```
<motion.div whileHover={{ scale: 1.05 }} whileTap={{ scale: 1 }}>
.......some icon to hover......
</motion.div>

```

Comment: I was suggesting dynamically importing the components where framer-motion is being used instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
const MotionDiv = dynamic(() =>
  import("framer-motion").then((mod) => mod.motion.div)
);
<MotionDiv
                    animate={{
                      rotate: activeIndex === index ? 180 : 0,
                    }}
                    className='flex h-6 w-6 items-center justify-center'
                  >
</MotionDiv>
```